# How do annihilationists understand Matthew 10:15?

Tags: exegesis, gospel-of-matthew, christian-mortalism

*Matthew 10:15* reads: "*Truly I tell you, it will be more bearable for Sodom and Gomorrah on the day of judgment than for that town.*" NIV

How do annihilationists like Jehovah's Witnesses or Adventists understand this verse?

Comment: I not understanding your question.

Comment: How does this impact on annihilationism ? I think we need more clarity and detail rather than just a one sentence question and a quoted text. What do you, yourself, see as relevant ?

Comment: Are you asking  “how can the  inhabitants of Sodom and Gomorrah be present on judgement day if they have  Been annihilated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Annihilationism allows for different degrees of punishment on the Day of Judgment, so long as the wicked are ultimately destroyed rather than enduring everlasting torment. Below is a response to this specific verse from "rethinkinghell".

https://rethinkinghell.com/explore/

> Those arguing for the traditional view of hell often appeal to such
> texts as this and others like it as evidence that final punishment
> will be meted out in varying degrees, according to each individual’s
> level of guilt before God. This is contrary to the conditionalist
> view, they suggest, which holds that all unsaved human beings will
> eventually cease to be.
>
> Yet none of these texts indicate exactly how varying degrees of
> punishment will be accounted for. They indicate only that the day of
> judgment will be more tolerable for some than for others, and that
> each person will be judged according to his works. Only the text in
> Luke is more explicit, but its servants who are beaten with different
> numbers or severity of blows appear in a parable, one that is not
> taken literally by even most traditionalists.
>
> Conditionalists debate amongst themselves when it comes to how degrees
> of punishment will play out. Perhaps some will be forever remembered
> as more shameful than others (cf. Daniel 12:2), much like Hitler’s
> legacy of evil is considered more contemptible than that of less
> noteworthy unbelievers. Alternatively, the annihilationist view allows
> for an array of possible combinations of type, intensity and duration
> of suffering as part of the process by which the lost are destroyed.
> Perhaps it is these differences in the degree of suffering,
> experienced while being destroyed, that accounts for degrees of
> punishment.
>
> In the end, conditionalists can account for degrees of punishment in
> multiple possible ways, though they might hasten to add that “the
> wages of sin is death” (Romans 6:23), and that “whoever keeps the
> whole law but fails in one point has become accountable for all of it”
> (James 2:10), and as such everyone deserves death.